# AWS Cognito Reset Password Verify Code then Reset Password

Tags: amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-cognito

Is there any way using AWS Cognito to send the user their verification code, have them enter the code, verify it is a valid code, THEN have them set their username and password?

For some reason, the workflow in my mind seems strange for the user to enter their code and new password in the same step.  I want to check their code, and if it is valid, then take them to the screen to reset their password.

So far I've used the API function call:

```
forgotPassword
```

To send the code, which works fine, and from all my reading of the docs and searching here and online, I see that the next step is to call:

```
confirmForgotPassword
```

But in this step, it requires the new password (from what I can tell from the documentation):

```
$result = $client->confirmForgotPassword([
    'AnalyticsMetadata' => [
        'AnalyticsEndpointId' => '<string>',
    ],
    'ClientId' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'ClientMetadata' => ['<string>', ...],
    'ConfirmationCode' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'Password' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'SecretHash' => '<string>',
    'UserContextData' => [
        'EncodedData' => '<string>',
    ],
    'Username' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
]);
```

Am I missing something?

For context, I'm using the PHP API, but I'm really just looking for the correct API calls in the correct order to accomplish what I'd like if it is even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The current workflow is one of the stupidest I've ever seen in my life. Why would anyone have the user enter both the password and verification code on the same page? Never seen that anywhere.

Comment: I agree, which is why I posted the question.  It seems to be the way AWS is setup.  If you see below, I was able to get around it adjusting the lambda functions to send the email with the code, then it popped up a link in my app with the code, validated it, and if it was valid (behind the scenes) enabled them to change the password.

Comment: I'm interested in such a solution with a link. Could you please provide more information on how you did it? It'd be awesome if you could show a code snippet of the lambda function and where you placed it in the api code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my workflow so that I used a lambda function in AWS to send a link with the code, this way I validate the code on the link click and then the user can enter their password in.

Doesn't seem possible to do this in two steps.

Comment: How do you validate the code on the link click? Is there a way to validate only the code?

Comment: @Rob Santoro do you still have the code that you implemented for the AWS lambda code?